# JsonResponse returns the json response plus the request data in string format problem

Tags: ajax, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-4.4, fosjsroutingbundle

I'm making post requests using ajax in my symfony 4.4 project, and i return the response using fosrestbundle, sometimes it returns a correct json response but sometimes, the response includes also the data sent with request as a string, which is strange, and i don't know why.

This is my ajax request (** i'm using jsrouting-bundle to embed my routes into javascript):

```
 var url = Routing.generate('orders_change_status', {id: order.id}, true);
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
           
        }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            
        }
    });
```

And this is my response :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/orders/change_status/{id}", name="orders_change_status", methods={"PUT"})
 */
public function changeStatus(Request $request, $id)
{
    $status = $request->request->get("status");
    if (isset($id) && isset($status)) {
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $apiResponse = $this->apiHelper->changeOrderStatus($id, $data);
        $jsonData = json_decode($apiResponse->getBody()->getContents());
        $checked = $this->hasErrors($apiResponse, $jsonData);

        if ($checked) {
            $flash = $request->request->get("flash");
            if (isset($flash) && $flash == 1)
                $this->addFlash('order_success', $this->translator->trans("The order has been edited successfully"));
            return new JsonResponse(array("code" => Response::HTTP_OK, "test" => "test"), Response::HTTP_OK);
        }
    }
    return View::create(array("code" => Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, "message" => "Something went wrong!"), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}

public function changeOrderStatus($id, $data)
{
    $data['author-id'] = $this->security->getUser()->getId();
    return $this->client->put($this->getApiUrl() . '/orders/' . $id . '/change_status', [
        'json' => $data
    ]);
}
```

Somtimes the response is correct in json format :

```
{"code":200,"message":"test"}
```

But sometimes it includes the data sent as a string, i don't know why  :

```
status=3&note=No+Answer&flash=1&postponed_to=2022-05-17+12%3A36{"code":200,"message":"test"}
```

***This happens only in production environment!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure there is no dump, echo and so on before your new JsonResponse ?

Comment: Yes, i've added the controller function

Comment: Can you show us changeOrderStatus as well ?

Comment: It has been added, i don't think it's cause of the problem, and it happens randomly

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging, I managed to resolve the problem by restarting all docker containers, many thanks anyway.